# Node Webkit / Electron Get apps running in background

Tags: node.js, electron, node-webkit

Is it possible to fetch list of apps running in the background using  nodewebkit or electron ?

I want to make an app for rendering secure videos ... so I want to make sure that apps like screen grab or screen recording isn't running in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are is a package for that:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node

### **However**

I will suggest that this is a poor solution for blocking screen capture. Trying to pursue this further will end up in a cat and mouse like game trying to block avenues of capture.

Its trivial to start an application with a different name to get past your list
or if trying to block by comparing executable hashes building the application with a different compiler can change the hash.

If you are ok with not having **absolute** security and making more of a best effort then i suggest you should explore, in addition to the above, using operating system support for blocking screencapture such as:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disable-screen-capture-00efe630

Comment: Thanks Much Megamit ... Just one quick question is it possible to integrate the disable screen capture plugin with nodewebkit? It does have a javascript version

Comment: The javascript engine that nodewebkit uses cannot make these api calls by default. For that to happen you would need to fork nodewebkit to add the functionality yourself or raise a feature request [here](https://github.com/nwjs/npm-installer/issues) though its unlikely to be added